# Winforms application requests admin rights

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio-2005

When I build and run my application, it requests me admin rights automatically.

I do not remember if I have experimented in the past with manifest files and the mt.exe tool in order to elevate admin rights.

I do not have any post build events defined and no manifest files.

Why is it asking me admin rights, and how can this behaviour be changed?

Comment: which operating system? does it ask to elevate to admin only if you start debugger from Visual Studio or also if you compile it then you double click on it in Windows Explorer?

Comment: Stab in the dark.. is the application called setup or install or anything similar?

Comment: yes it contains the word update.. see my comment

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this page: [Understanding and Configuring User Account Control in Windows Vista](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/00d04415-2b2f-422c-b70e-b18ff918c281.aspx), especially around "Installer Detection Technology"

Comment: Thanks guys for your answers ! Indeed, my application contained the word Updater. Despite this, i changed both the assembly name,namespace etc. to Synchronizer and it still requires elevated admin rights. I also changed the name to a.exe just for a test and it still requires admin rights.

Comment: I found it... I should change the namespace of my .NET application also. It should not contain the word Updater..